# Vim: Expand tabs in paste mode

Tags: vim, paste

Vim's [paste mode](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste) ignores `expandtab` setting when pasting, i.e., tabs are maintained. This is explicitly considered a feature, [not a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1576583).

Is there a config that will make Vim respect `expandtab` when pasting in paste mode to keep the document tab-free.

Answer (score 1):

Paste mode means pasting "as-is", without Vim applying any formatting rules. That's usually what you want.

If you need to convert tabs in your buffer to spaces, use `:retab` while `'expandtab'` is on.

See `:h :retab` for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately it's never what I want since my code doesn't have tabs, but some examples include tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `paste` resets `expandtab`, but you can still set `expandtab` after setting `paste`.

You could define a function that turns on paste mode, and *then, afterwards* turns on expandtab again.